# remove() function working on even index values only in for loop

Tags: python, iteration

I am new to Python and I tried running the below code, which defines a list and iterates through it, removing the element at index "x".

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

for x in list1:
 
 list1.remove(x)
 
 print(list1)
```

However it is removing elements at even indexes only, as you can see from the visual example below:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JZRD.png)

How can I modify my code to make it obtain the below output?

```
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[3, 4, 5, 6]
[4, 5, 6]
[5, 6]
[6]
[]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Never** remove elements whilst you are iterating through the **same** list.

As the list is modified as you iterate, the iterator will correspond to an element of the list which is *not* what you expect anymore.

To solve it, iterate through a **copy** of the list, using the `[:]` syntax:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
for x in list1[:]:
  list1.remove(x)
  print(list1)
```